# How to refresh the backroundcolor of only one cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, io

In my project I have to visualize the states of a decentralized periphery. I can also access a single cell in the DataGridView. The code looks like this.

```
if (newStatus == 1) // Status = 1 => green Status = 0 => red
{
Dgv_Data_List.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Adresse"].Style.BackColor = Color.Green; // e is from DataGridViewCellContent_Click event 
Dgv_Data_List.Refresh();
}
```

I control the state and then let the cell turn green for a 1 and red for 0. However, the method Refresh() always redraws the complete DataGridView. Is there a possibility in which only the single cell is changed. If not, maybe it's because of the color and would it be possible with a simple numerical value in your Extra column for the state, then just change the single cells at runtime via the program?

Comment: DGV cells are just virtual. So, no they all need to be drawn together. But: In the CellPainiting event you can skip cells and paint only those you want by testing the column/rowIndices.